# Debugger stops before breakpoint in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am a total VSCode noob so please bear with me. I am trying to debug a codebase which has been provided to me by someone else. Running the code in its current state throws a `TypeError` at line 921. I place a breakpoint in this line and try to rerun the code for debugging. The debugger does not stop at line 921 but at line 919. It still throws a `TypeError`, but refers to line 919.

Here are some observations I've made:

- The line at which the debugger stops is not actually covered by this particular run.
- If I place the breakpoint at this other line (line 919), the debugger will actually skip it, and stop at the line which causes the `TypeError` (line 921)
- Placing a breakpoint at any covered line besides line 921 causes the debugger to stop at the breakpoint as expected.

Coming from Pycharm, I would have expected the debugger to stop at line 921. Why does it stop at a different line?

Please let me know if you would like me to provide additional information.

**EDIT**

It seems that checking the "Raised Exceptions" option in the "BREAKPOINTS" settings causes the debugger to stop at the right line (line 921):

[image]

Does anyone know what this option is about? Is it part of the core VSCode functionality or the python extension?

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm trying to see if I can do that. The issue is that it occurs in a large codebase which was provided to me by someone else. Hard to isolate...

Comment: You could try to isolate the problem first: if you suspect it's a bug or quirk with VS code's python debugger, try to create a small sample script and run it through the debugger to see if it behaves as you expect. If not, something else is probably throwing errors in your codebase.

Comment: Like I said, that's what I'm trying to do. Let's not go in circles here...

Comment: @user32882 Is the code running successfully when no breakpoint is set for it? Since Python debugging in VSCode is provided by Python extensions, you could try to disabled other extensions and install Python extensions again. In addition, have you tried to use other versions of Python extensions?